# I keep getting my questions on hold because it's not about site I control

Tags: discussion

Basically I am asking about CloudFare, which is a service many webmasters used. Of course I do not own CloudFare. Whoever, there are many other users that also ask about CloudFare and it's okay.

What is the problem for my question and what is the different between my question and all other CloudFare question out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes we moderators make mistakes.   When your questions get closed, the recommended course of action is to edit the question to make it completely obvious that it should not have been closed.   When you edit a closed question it automatically enters the "re-open queue" and must be re-evaluated.

For example, change the title of:

"How can cloudfare obfuscate IPs" to "Avoid having my sites linked as hosted together by obfuscating IPs on CloudFlare"

Again, please do not ask the same question, or very similar questions in the hopes that it will "get by" the second time.

Comment: Yep, and that's why Stack Exchange introduced the hold status rather than closed.